# How do i open a com port(rs422) on linux os?

Tags: c++, linux

Is there any C++ example which i can read up on?

Comment: What is this "linux os" you are talking about. Be more specific. C++ example sounds to me overly broad.

Comment: Hi, im using fedora 11. is there any c++ project which has the functionally of writing and reading of the serial port. Thx!

Comment: Which RS-422 card? You'll have to look into details of the card

Comment: Have you checked this one http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use the [open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open), [close(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/close), [read(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), [write(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write), [ioctl(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl), [fcntl(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) system calls.

Serial ports are quite complex things. read about their [ioctl commands](http://linux.die.net/man/4/tty_ioctl) and [termios](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios)

Read a good book about [linux programming](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (or about [advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/)). Serial ports, and  [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) (including pseudo-ttys) are complex!

Answer (score 1):

Very few computers have [RS-422](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422) ports, is that a typo of RS-232 ("plain old serial port")?

Anyway, Linux uses [device drivers](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/1019/1) to make various hardware devices available as files that you can open. These files are usually located in the `/dev/` directory. You can probably inspect the kernel's boot up messages (run the `dmesg` command) to see which device name is associated with the serial port in question, and then `open()` it.