# PC hardware port access from Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, port, hardware-interface, hardware-port

What is the Java-on-Linux equivalent to the C byte-sized PC-architecture hardware port input/output functions?

For output there is `outb` as in this:

```
tmp = inb(0x61);
if (tmp != (tmp | 0x01)) 
    outb(0x61, tmp | 0x01);
```

For input there is `inb` as in this:

```
tmp = (inb(0x61) & 0xfe);
outb(0x61, tmp);
```

Purpose:  I want to implement something that imposes less overhead than this:

```
try { Runtime.getRuntime().exec("beep") } catch (IOException e) {}
```

as an alternative to sending code 7 (the bell char) to the standard output because that seems to have been aggressively disabled in Ubuntu.  Toolkit's beep is also mute.

Comment: In Linux, everything is file.

Comment: You can run C on Linux (obviously), so that proves not all Linux I/O is file oriented.

Comment: No! Kangkan is suggesting you to open some device file like e.g. `/dev/tty0` or `/dev/lp0`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8923009/841108 and http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/

Comment: If you need that exact functionality, use jni - write a small C function, build it into a shared library, load it, and call into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're barking up the wrong train.

Java is a object-oriented high-level language compiling to a virtual machine architecture. Assembler I/O instructions are hardware processor specific. There is no direct equivalence between the two.

The best you could hope for is to interface your Java code (using pipes, shared memory, sockets, etc) with a native Linux app which performs the required I/O.

Comment: Update: my purpose has been described.

Comment: So your actual question is: "How do I create a system beep from Java?"  That seems like a monumentally different question to "PC hardware port access from Java on Linux".

Comment: Still I/O what I need because it's been a huge waste of time trying to make sounds any other way.  And I've tried many. The example code is not assembler: it's processor agnostic code.

Comment: Anything that involves inb()/outb() it NOT processor agnostic.  The I/O operations are unique to x86.

Comment: There are C compilers that are not x86 so there must be inb() and outb() that are non x86.

Comment: @broiyan inb() and outb() are platform-specific functions.  They are not in the ANSI C Libraries anywhere.  In fact, most non-x86 processors do not even have I/O space (they do everything memory-mapped).

Comment: This answer is not useful, as it is written from the mistaken premise that because java *can* be platform neutral, it would only ever be used in such a way.  And no, interacting with a distinct process is not a requirement - like almost every other practical language, java permits calling functions written in other languages.